# Printing an image to a dye based application

Tags: webgl, haxe

I am learning about fluid dynamics (and Haxe) and have come across [this](https://github.com/haxiomic/GPU-Fluid-Experiments/tree/snow) awesome project and thought I would try to extend to it to help me learn. A demo of the original project in action can be seen [here](http://haxiomic.github.io/GPU-Fluid-Experiments/html5/).

So far, I have created a side menu of items containing different shapes. When the user clicks on one of the shapes, then, clicks onto the canvas, the image selected should be imprinted onto the dye. The user will then move the mouse and explore the art etc.

To try and achieve this I did the following:

```
import js.html.webgl.RenderingContext;

function imageSelection(): Void{        

    document.querySelector('.myscrollbar1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // twilight image clicked
    closeNav(); 
    reset(); 
    var image:js.html.ImageElement = cast document.querySelector('img[src="images/twilight.jpg"]');
    gl.current_context.texSubImage2D(cast fluid.dyeRenderTarget.writeToTexture, 0, Math.round(mouse.x), Math.round(mouse.y), RenderingContext.RGB, RenderingContext.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    TWILIGHT = true;  

});
```

After this call, inside the update function, I have the following:

```
override function update( dt:Float ){

        time = haxe.Timer.stamp() - initTime;
        performanceMonitor.recordFrameTime(dt);
        //Smaller number creates a bigger ripple, was 0.016
        dt = 0.090;//@!
        //Physics
        //interaction
        updateDyeShader.isMouseDown.set(isMouseDown && lastMousePointKnown);
        mouseForceShader.isMouseDown.set(isMouseDown && lastMousePointKnown);

        //step physics
        fluid.step(dt);

        particles.flowVelocityField = fluid.velocityRenderTarget.readFromTexture;

        if(renderParticlesEnabled){
            particles.step(dt);
        }

//Below handles the cycling of colours once the mouse is moved and then the image should be disrupted into the set dye colours.

}
```

However, although the project builds, I can't seem to get the image imprinted onto the canvas. I have checked the console log and I can see the following error:

> WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: texSubImage2D: invalid texture target

Is it safe to assume that my cast for the first param is not allowed?

I have read that the texture target is the first parameter and `INVALID_ENUM` in particular means that one of the `gl.XXX` parameters are just flat out wrong for that particular function.

Looking through to the file `writeToTexture` is declared as so: `public var writeToTexture (default, null):GLTexture;`. `WriteToTexture` is a wrapper around a regular webgl handle.

I am using `Haxe version 3.2.1` and using `Snow` to build the project. `WriteToTexture` is defined inside `HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\gltoolbox\git\gltoolbox\render`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writeToTexture` in [`gltoolbox`](https://github.com/haxiomic/gltoolbox) is a `GLTexture`. With [`snow`](https://github.com/snowkit/snow) and `snow_web`, this is defined in `snow.modules.opengl.GL` as:

```
typedef GLTexture = js.html.webgl.Texture;
```

So we're simply dealing with a [`js.html.webgl.Texture`](https://api.haxe.org/js/html/webgl/Texture.html?) here, or [`WebGLTexture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLTexture) in native JS.

Which means that yes, this is definitely not a valid value for `texSubImage2D()`'s `target`, [which is specified to take one of the `gl.TEXTURE_*` constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D#Parameters).

> A `GLenum` specifying the binding point (target) of the active texture.

From this description it's obvious that the parameter isn't actually for the texture itself - it merely gives some info on *how* the *active* texture should be used.

The question then becomes how the "active" texture can be set. [`bindTexture()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bindTexture) can be used for this.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying in such detail. I think I will have to figure out some other way to render the image in the dye when the canvas is clicked on!